# Are there any official restrictions per Twin Galaxies relating to walking away from a game?

Tags: arcade

Suppose I'm playing for a world record and planning to submit to Twin Galaxies and the game can be negotiated into a stable state where I can physically leave the cabinet for an arbitrarily long time without ending the credit. For example, Galaga's Stage 0, where I can move the ship to the edge of the screen and be functionally guaranteed that it will never get hit so long as it doesn't move.

Once I get the game in that state, are there any official restrictions on what I'm allowed to do? For example, leaving longer than a certain amount of time or going a certain distance from the machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The Twin Galaxies' policy is that there is no formalized "break" offered. Rather, the gamer is allowed to spend as little or as much time away from their game in progress as they want, mid-attempt, and must be responsible for the results of their actions.
>
> Thus, if a gamer wishes to rest while 800 men on "Q*Bert" are lost in
> the process, that is their decision to do so, and at their own risk.
>
> During these self-imposed "breaks" the gamer's attempt must remain
> untouched by another individual, or the game attempt becomes void.
> However, during this time, the controls may be adjusted / tightened
> providing the actions are caught on camera.
>
> Some games have a non-glitch tactic available which allows the gamer
> to set up or create an artificial "break" in the action, which further
> allows them to enter a state where their game is in little or no
> danger of changing in immediate status for a period of time. Such
> titles would be the “pacman-type” series in which "hiding spots" allow
> refuge for a few minutes until the ghosts reverse directions.
>
> Such tactics are allowable ONLY IF this situation is temporary and
> eventually changes on it's own accord. However, some non-glitch
> tactics can provide refuge for an indeterminate period of time. Using
> these tactics, only a fifteen (15) minute break is allowed every 3
> hours.
>
> For example, in "Tron", a gamer in the "Red Tank Wave" can hide in the
> top right corner for a lengthy period of time, and is therefore
> invalid for usage in marathon gameplay unless the gamer only does so
> for 15 minutes every 3 hours.

[-Twin Galaxies Marathon Policy](https://www.twingalaxies.com/wiki_index.php?title=Policy:Video-Game-Marathoning-A-Policy-Information-and-Guide)

So this would be allowed only for a 15 minute break every 3 hours.